# How to do backup / source version control for Hive Queries in Beeswax

Tags: hive, hue

The HUE/beeswax interface conveniently allows to save queries. I'd like to have a little more control.

**What would be a good way to put the saved queries under version control or back them up?**

Background: Currently I edit the queries in a normal editor and save them as .hive (+ normal hg/git) to execute I copy the query into the execute query in hue/beeswax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are pain-points that are targeted in the 2.3 release.

Right now there is not way to export/import queries: everything stays in the Hue database.

In [HUE-950](https://issues.cloudera.org/browse/HUE-950) it is planned to have the queries editor save queries back to a file (that could be version controlled). A trash mechanism is also going to be added.

Also, directly using files from a version control repository will be done in [HUE-951](https://issues.cloudera.org/browse/HUE-951).

This is more discussed in this [thread](https://groups.google.com/a/cloudera.org/group/hue-user/browse_thread/thread/56d8d8663fb21649#) on the [Hue mailing list](https://groups.google.com/a/cloudera.org/forum/?fromgroups=#!forum/hue-user).